# Multiple Queues in a single thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, queue, pthreads

I was recently asked this question in one of the interviews. I would like to know what's the best way to implement this.

Say I have 3 threads t1, t2, t3 and two queues q1, q2.
t1 writes data to q1
t2 writes data to q2
t3 should read data from q1 and q2 as soon as it's available.

I thought I can use conditional variables to read from both q1 and q2. Is that possible or are there any better approaches.

Comment: Have you considered using local sockets (`AF_LOCAL`) for queuing and use the `select()` or `pselect()` function for passive wait?

Comment: @FabienBouleau Pipes would work, too.

Comment: @FabienBouleau Yes. This approach is very much possible. Thanks. Any idea how to achieve the same with queues ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I had some trouble with pipes in the past. I remember well, it was that you have one reader only (first reader first served). But in this case you are right, since there is one reader only.

Comment: @FabienBouleau use the socket stack or pipes for this?  Sledgehammer/nut.

Comment: @MartinJames My advice is to use sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Have t3 wait on a semaphore.  t1, t2 queue up data and post a unit to the semaphore.  When t3 runs, it polls both queues once for an item to process, (there WILL be data in one of them), and handles that dequeues/handles that one item and then loops back to wait on the semaphore again for more items.

I assume that the queue class is thread-safe, (else protect with mutex).